# Error is Duplicate files copied in META-INF/LICENSE jackson files

Tags: android, build.gradle

[gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7jiE.jpg)

[gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1O3L.jpg)

These are my gradle console error and file as well
Suggest new ideas to resolve the error, I tried all previous solutions, didn't work.

Comment: Are you using jackson dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **10.2.0** instead of **10.0.1**

**No Need**

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2' // Remove this
```

**Do this**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0' 
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0"
```

**Then**

```
android {
.....
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
   }
}
```

Finally **Clean-Rebuild and Run** .